# How to work return without print function?

Tags: python, linked-list

```
def __str__(self):
    vals = []
    node = self.head
    while node is not None:
        vals.append(node.val)
        node = node.next
    return f"[{','.join(str(val) for val in vals)}]"
```

**Actually I want to know how to work return type above this code? I really tired to do understand.**

```
 return f"[{','.join(str(val) for val in vals)}]"
```

**How does work this line?**

*Thank you!*

Answer (score 1):

This is python `f-string`.

look at this [Link](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for more information.

```
>>> name = "Eric"
>>> age = 74
>>> f"Hello, {name}. You are {age}."
'Hello, Eric. You are 74.'
```

The rest of it is working with `join()`.

Comment: There's a bit more to it though. Inside the `{...}` we have a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) building up the items to print, and a [join](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) gluing them together. It isn't clear which part -- maybe all -- that the OP is struggling with.